# Pull to refresh UITableView without UITableViewController is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, pull-to-refresh

I can't seem to find a working solution. I've tried the other available solutions to implement pull to refresh in a UITableView without a UITableViewController but nothing happens.

This is the relevant code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var peopleRefreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    peopleRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    peopleRefreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    peopleRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    // I also tried this
    // peopleRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refresh"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(peopleRefreshControl)

}

func refresh(){
    println("what!")
}
```

I can see the circle spinning and the text "Pull to refresh" when I pull down, but the function "refresh" is never called. What am I doing wrong? Is there something else that I should be doing? I'm not doing anything special with the tableView other than hiding it when it's not being used. Could that somehow be a problem?

**Edit**: I updated the code to include ":" as follows but there was absolutely no change. I still see the circle spinning and the text "Pull to refresh" but the text "what!" is never printed out.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...
    peopleRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    ...
}

func refresh(sender:UIRefreshControl){
    println("what!")
}
```

Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you did not add a ":" after the word refresh in the viewDidLoad. 
Without it, the refresh function won't run.
Try using this code...

```
var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

  override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

//look at the : after "refresh" 
        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


        self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
```

Comment: I modified my previous code to include the ":", but it didn't change anything. I still see the animation from the pulldown but the text "what!" is never printed out

Comment: Use the exact code i have above in my answer, and not your code.

Comment: I tried your code with func refresh(sender:UIRefreshControl) and func refresh(sender:AnyObject) but it still has no effect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, however I found that mine was due to the tableview being halfway down the screen - this meant that i didn't have enough room to pull the table enough to trigger it.

You could try calling the refresh manually from the scroll view delegate - perhaps checking the content offset.y and firing your method in there?

Answer (score -1):

Your prototypes are not quite right for the target action. The action takes the sender as the argument and you need a `:` on the selector:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var peopleRefreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    peopleRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    peopleRefreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    peopleRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(peopleRefreshControl)
  }

func refresh(sender:AnyObject){
    println("what!")
}
```

Comment: I updated the my code to match exactly what you gave me, but it didn't have any effect. It still has the same problem where "what!" is never printed out

Comment: @user2492566 Only other suggestion is to change the refresh function to use AnyObject as edited in answer, however should not make a difference. What you have seems common based on many answers online. It is possible that this approach nolonger works. An alternative is to embed a UITableViewController inside a container view, which will give you the built in pull down and still allow you to add views around the table in the main controller.